# Memory Could not be Written Error on MSI

Tags: .net, windows-7, windows-installer, setup-project, .net-1.1

I'm trying to install an application using a VS Setup project for .NET 1.1 in Windows7 (with the .NET framework 1.1 already installed).

The installer has 2 projects it uses for configurations, where the first one is called `CustomActions.vb` and has only an installer class also called CustomActions in it (aside of the AssemblyInfo).

If the installer attempts to run that project, through it's `Custom Actions`, I get the following error:

[image]

Removing that project from the installer makes it install just fine. I even stripped the `CustomActions` project of all the code and left a dummy with empty functions and removed the argument passed to the install sub through `CustomActionData`. Didn't work :(.

P.S. The installer works well in Windows XP and I even turned UAC off for tests (though I need it to also work with UAC on).

Comment: Might be worthwhile upgrading the project to a higher version of .NET

Comment: I've been trying to push that request ever since I got here... higher ops love this :'( so it's all I got for now.

Comment: In the absence of an answer your higher ups may be forced to relent, at least copy your project and try it so the cause can be pinpointed.

Comment: When you're coding for .NET 1.1 all you got is VS 2003 [pain] I don't have a newer VS version that supports a newer framework.

Comment: What happens when you run the application manually after install? Does it still crash?

Comment: The application doesn't install, when the installer hits the project (that's what it seems) it gives me that error and rolls-back.

Comment: What do you mean hits the project? Are you launching your application or a custom action? If you're launching your application, what happens when you just install it without launching it during install?

Comment: By hit I mean the moment in which the Setup runs the `Install` method on the `CustomActions` which as the name implies is a custom action. If I launch it with the custom action it installs well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with Windows 7 and the Installer class, at the end I was not able to solve the issue, what I did was create a console application with the same logic as the installer class and that got me through. Anyhow it is stated that there is [no support from Windows 7 (nor Windows Server 2008) for .NET 1.1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2489698)

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error message when I tested my C#/C++ project in the past. My C# code called native function using P/Invoke. This error message appeared when null reference exception was raised in native function. Try to improve logging and error checking in your projects.

Comment: Problem is that not even a line of code of the installer executes... I tried setting a msgbox as the first line of code and it didn't even show...